# React Native ref is undefined when re-rendering a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem with refs on React Native. This is a simplified version of my code:

```
class Main extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        ...
        this.refs = {};
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.page=="index") {
            return(
                <View>
                    <FlatList ref={flatlist => this.refs.flatlist = flatlist}> ... </FlatList>
                    <MyActionButton flatlist={this.refs.flatlist}/>
                </View>
            )

        } else if (this.state.page="text"=){
            return(
                <Text> ... </Text>
            )
        }
    }
}


class MyActionButton extends React.Component {
    render(
        return(
            <ActionButton>
                <ActionButtonItem onPress={() => {
                    console.log("AB props", this.props)
                }} />
            </ActionButton>
        )
    )
}
```

The app starts with this.state.page = "index" so when I press MyActionButton I see the log as expected, and things seem to work:

```
'AB props', {flatlist: {A LOT OF STUFF HERE}}
```

However If I change the state.page to "text" and then come back to "index" again, when I press MyActionButton I get:

```
'AB props', {flatlist: undefined}
```

I'm not sure why that prop gets undefined and how to fix it to make it point to the actual FlatList.

Comment: First of all, you should use ref callbacks instead of string refs. Secondly, can you explain what you want to achieve

Comment: I have changed it to callbacks and still the same. The button just calls scrollToOffset on the flatlist, so the app crashes when it is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like very much, but I managed to get it working by changing the reference to a getter funcion

```
class Main extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        ...
        this.refs = {};
    }

    getFlatList() {
        return this.refs.flatlist;
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.page=="index") {
            return(
                <View>
                    <FlatList ref={flatlist => this.refs.flatlist = flatlist}> ... </FlatList>
                    <MyActionButton flatlist={this.getFlatList.bind(this)}/>
                </View>
            )

        } else if (this.state.page="text"=){
            return(
                <Text> ... </Text>
            )
        }
    }
}
```